# Add comment to an item in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

The question and answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159844/93163) propose a way to display a `note` field before items in the the biblio. I am wondering if I can change this in two ways:

- I want the note to be after the biblio item rather than before.
- Also, I have one universal biblio file that I use in all my latex files and I want to include different notes in different latex files. So I am wondering if I can add the note as part of the latex file rather than the bib file.

Below is a MWE (stolen from the answer above) but with what I would like to acheive

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A2011,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2011},
  title = {A short title.}
}
@misc{A2012,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2012},
  title = {Systems biology and personalized medicine are two emerging research areas, which promise to transform our health system.}
}
@misc{A2013,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2013},
  title = {This title is not so short.}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{A2012, A2013}

% Add notes to entries
%\addbibnote{A2012}{This is the first note}
%\addbibnote{A2013}{Another note}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify the bibmacro `finentry` in order to print your note at the end of an entry. See for example also [How to move the note field out and away from the main reference using biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91304/35864) and [Print and format Mendeley Notes field (annote) in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442062/35864).

If you prefer not to give the note in the `.bib` file, we can instead define a new command to collect the note.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{entrynote}{\small\itshape #1}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\addentrynote}[2]{%
  \csdef{tohikoblx@entrynote@\the\c@refsection @#1}{#2}}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \ifcsundef{tohikoblx@entrynote@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}
    {}
    {\setunit{\finentrypunct\par}%
     \printtext[entrynote]{\csuse{tohikoblx@entrynote@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}}%
     \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}}%
  \finentry
}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer}

% Add notes to entries
\addentrynote{sigfridsson}{This is the first note.}
\addentrynote{worman}{Another note}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Geer, Ingrid de (1985). “Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald – and Music. The Orkney Earldom of the Twelfth Century. A Musicological Study”. PhD thesis. Uppsala: Uppsala Universitet. Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998). “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P. This is the first note. Worman, Nancy (2002). The Cast of Character. Style in Greek Literature. Austin: University of Texas Press. Another note]