# Add white space to bibliography annotations

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, annotations

I am working on annotating part of a bibliography within a larger document and have found the code from the answer on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640207/add-comment-to-an-item-in-the-bibliography) to be extremely helpful, but I would like to add a small amount white space before the entries to help separate them from the text of the reference itself. I can't figure out how to do this as I have tried add \vspace{0.2cm} in various parts of the command but everything seems to add a space after the first line of the annotation, but I want one before the annotation. I would have commented on the original post but I lack the reputation to do so. Perhaps the person who posted the original solution (@moewe) will find this and offer some help, but I am open to any solutions.

Thank you all very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the spacing before paragraphs and between items using `\bibparsep` and `\bibitemsep`. e.g., try:

```
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\bigskipamount}
\setlength{\bibparsep}{\medskipamount}
```

Adjust to your liking.